# Why do I get better numeric results when using a matrix $A^\ast A$ instead of using $A$ itself?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

I have a formula for the value of $\phi$ such the a matrix $A = A(\phi)$ becomes singular.

To check this formula I run a simulation in Matlab where I provide $A$ with a range of values of $\phi$ and observe for which $\phi$ the minimum eigenvalue of $A$ is closest to zero.

The thing is, if I just use $A$ 'as is' in the simulation code I don't get a good match between the formula and the simulation. However if I use $A^\ast A$ instead (which is singular when $A$ is singular) I get a very good match.

I believe I recall once hearing something about $A^\ast A$ being more numerically stable than $A$, and that $A^\ast A$ is a 'better' matrix than $A$.

So why am I getting much better results using $A^\ast A$? Can anyone shed some light on the potential reasons for this?

Comment: Is $A$ symmetric?   Can $A$ have negative or complex eigenvalues?

Comment: A is not symmetric and it can have complex eigenvalues.

Comment: In that case, what do you mean by "minimum eigenvalue of $A$" when you say you observe for which $\phi$ the minimum eigenvalue of $A$ is closest to zero?